# Communication between 2 Services running on same system using C++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, service, ipc

In C++, I've 2 services (say windows services) that are running on a system. Obviously both have their corresponding EXEs A.EXe & B.EXE.

If i want to query & receive some data between these 2 windows services can it be done as a function call by passing a pointer of a struct from 1 service & have the other service fill the struct using the pointer passed.

Common header file for both A & B:

```
struct Abc
    {
       int a;
    }
```

Now say service A sends this struct object with its pointer or as pass by reference by calling a function in service B.EXE. Will this function call work across 2 services & can the data be transferred between A & B this way?

Or do i need an IPC mechanism like sockets.

> Whats the best way for achieving the data transfer between 2 services
>   running on same system

Comment: Have a look at Boost asio chatserver example , it supports duplex communication through socket.

Comment: If you want this communication to proceed as function calls, may be you can try *Remote Procedure Calls*. As you are using Windows and VS, check [Introduction to RPC - Part 1](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4837/Introduction-to-RPC-Part) and part 2 for a good introduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPC stands for "inter process communication".  You have two services (each running in their own process) and you want to communicate between them.  You are *absolutely* going to need an IPC mechanism.

Your choices are:

- sockets (layering `boos::asio` on top would be an excellent idea)
- Shared memory mapping and signalling events (don't forget to use a mutex or similar, and don't forget to establish a lock hierarchy so you don't get deadlocks).  This will be limited to a single machine, but that may be acceptable.
- DCOM (Windows only, but it looks like you are limited to Windows anyway).
- Some other IPC package.

My personal preference would be sockets, but any of them could be appropriate.

Comment: Thank you. Few clarifications as asked in my question also,
1) Is it not possible to do the function call from one service to another ?
2) Can the pointer be passed between the 2 services (processes) ?

I think the answer to both these is NO.

Comment: DCOM (and possibly other packages) will make it look as if you are doing a function call from one service to another, but in reality all the arguments are serialized, copied from one process to anthor, processed, and then everything copied back.  You cannot literally call a function in one process from another process.